# in_array strange logic: in_array("0E3", ["0E97", "0E27"]) === true

Tags: php

I check the `hachids` package for collision, but I have a strange result in my checking script (on macOS 10.12.6).

I rewrite some code from my checking script and give a question:

```
# php -v
PHP 7.1.11 (cli) (built: Oct 27 2017 11:00:43) ( NTS )


# php -a

php > $hashes = array('0E97', '0E27');
php > var_dump($hashes);
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  string(4) "0E97"
  [1]=>
  string(4) "0E27"
}
php > $c = '0E3';
php > var_dump($c);
string(3) "0E3"
php > var_dump(in_array($c, $hashes));
bool(true)
```

Why 'true'? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All three strings are numeric in the eyes of PHP; e (or E) in means exponent in this case and PHP separates the base from exponent (or power). For example `0E3` means `0*1000`, and the equivalent for the other two strings (just more zeros). Because of this PHP will treat the strings as numbers, and, since 0 multiplied with anything is 0, treat them all as equal.
If you have the letter in the strings is not `E` but e.g. `F` the strings would be different. Only e and E have this special meaning.

You can easily force a stricter check by calling:

```
 var_dump(in_array($c, $hashes, true));
```

This will only return true, when the strings are the same.

Comment: It's worth to add that `e` (or `E`) in means `exponent` in this case and it separates the base from exponent (or power).

Comment: Thanks @marekful, I included your comment into the answer. It's a lot better and more precise than putting zeros...